# Flex and Java Servlet: "Channel Security Error"

Tags: apache-flex, servlets

PROBLEM:

Unable to to send HTTP "GET" request from Flex to java-servlet.

Keep getting this error message: **[RPC Fault faultString="Security error accessing url" faultCode="Channel.Security.Error" faultDetail="Destination: DefaultHTTP"]**

DETAILS:

I have built a chess game using Flex for client-side and Java Web Application (based on servlets) for server-side.

I am hosting the flex-app on my PC (using HFS ~ HTTP File Server, listening on port 80) and the the java-web-app is running also on my PC (using glass-fish on NetBeans listening on port 8080).

When i run the flex app locally, from - D://path-to/flex-app.html - everything works perfectly fine, however, when i run the flex app from - 'http://domain-name/flex-app.html' - i get the error above and no request is being loged on the server.

I tried to add crossdomain.xml file to the server root folder, even the most permissive one, unsuccessfuly.

crossdomain.xml file (which is available at 'http://localhost:8080/crossdomain.xml')  as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all" />  
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" secure="false"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/> 
</cross-domain-policy>
```

In the flex Declarations section i have this httpService:

```
    <s:HTTPService id="loginService"
                   url="http://localhost:8080/Chess/Login" 
                   fault="onFault(event)"
                   result="login_onResult(event)"
                   resultFormat="object"
                   showBusyCursor="true"/>
```

thanks for help.

Comment: A SWF served off your file system is not subject to crossdomain restrictions; but a file served off a web server is.  You'll need a crossdomain.xml file on your server (AKA localhost:8080) in order to avoid the security error.  Also, you probably don't want to hard code 'localhost' into an application either.  You may want to post your crossdomain.xml file.

Comment: Hi, I edited my post added the crossdomain.xml file. I used "Charles - Web Debugging Proxy" (great tool to see requests traffic) and found out that the flex app requested to download the crossdomain.xml file from 'http://localhost:37813' rather than http://localhost:8080' which is the url I hard-coded.

Comment: +1 for using a network sniffer.  Could there be any sort of server redirect from port 8080 to port 37813?  Is there any other portion of the app that could make a call to port 37813?  Are you sure your Java server is configured on port 8080?

Comment: I don't know of any possible redirection and no other portion of the app could make a call to 37813. (Also, it is being sent with additional ?hostname="localhost:8080") Strange. Anyway, I deployed the server and flex app on another PC and everything works fine, so the main problem is gone. The reason for my problem was that I thought that the crossdomain.xml file should be accessible from the root of the web-app ('localhost:8080/Chess') when in fact **it should be accessible from the root of the server itself** ('localhost:8080/'). Thank you for helping.

Comment: If the Network Monitor is enabled in Flash Builder, any HTTPService request will return an HTTP 502 error associated with port localhost:37813 on the Google Chrome and Firefox browsers. IE 8 works fine. It does not matter if the application is run via debugging mode in Flash Builder or independently. The work around is to disable the network monitor.